# How can I make the angle of rays cast relative to mouse position?

Tags: java, raytracing

i'm struggling to word the question a little but I am essentially making a game in which the user will have a limited field of view, the game itself is top down but the player will have to interpret their surroundings based off of the interaction of their small field of view and the walls.

I have created the system for the raysy to be created, however I am struggling to work out the math behind, as well as the implementation of making the angle at which my rays come out of be relevant to the mouse position

code:

```
private LinkedList<Line2D.Float> calcRays(LinkedList<Line2D.Float> lines, int x, int y, int resolution, int maxDist){
    LinkedList<Line2D.Float> rays = new LinkedList<>();
    //field of view affected by i
    for(int i = 0 ; i < resolution; i++) {
        float angle = (float) Math.atan2(mosy - player.getY(), mosx - player.getX());
        double dir = (Math.PI*2) * (double) i / resolution / 15;

        float minDist = maxDist;
        for(Line2D.Float line : lines) {
            float dist = getRayCast(x, y, (player.getX()+16)+(float) Math.cos(dir) * maxDist, (player.getY()+16)+(float) Math.sin(dir) * maxDist, line.x1, line.y2, line.x2, line.y2);
            if(dist < minDist && dist > 0) {
                minDist = dist;
            }
        }
        rays.add(new Line2D.Float(x, y, (player.getX()+16)+(float) Math.cos(dir) * minDist, (player.getY()+16)+(float) Math.sin(dir) * minDist));
    }
    return rays;
}

public static float dist(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    return (float) Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
}

public static float getRayCast(float p0_x, float p0_y, float p1_x, float p1_y, float p2_x, float p2_y, float p3_x, float p3_y) {
    float s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
    s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;
    s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
    s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;
    s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;

    float s, t;
    s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
    t = (s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

    if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
        // Collision detected
        float x = p0_x + (t * s1_x);
        float y = p0_y + (t * s1_y);

        return dist(p0_x, p0_y, x, y);
    }

    return -1; // No collision
}
```

This is all of the code related to calculating the ray casts, if anyone would be able to show me how I can add this feature i'd be extremely grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Why does this question have the [swing] tag? Swing is a UI toolkit for Java. The code you have shown us so far soes not make use of Swing in any way.

Comment: My apologies, not totally sure why I included that? Maybe because my overall program uses swing and I wasnt thinking about it

Comment: Is the question then about raycasting from a certain point in Java?